# custom pageview indicator and uipageviewcontroller using swipegester

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uipageviewcontroller

Making one registration form , it's content two page I use swipe for transfer right and left in page , 1st has 10 textfields and second has 5 textfields and one registration button.

Now after fill all 10 fields I swipe it's right side and get next view and clicking on register I submitted data in `JSON`,

Now my problem is that how i make two view in on controller and swipe them ??

I do code for `JSON` and validation from my side now need to know how make animation and swipe view.

Comment: take a scrollview and set proper content size and add textfiled based on your requirement along with page viewcontroller

Comment: any sample code for making custom page indicator and swipegester

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/) is the link for the tutorial for UIPageViewController. Good tutorial. The two methods

`viewControllerBeforeViewController:` and `viewControllerAfterViewController:` are all that u need.

and i've been searching for another link that is very easy to understand. just wait i'll be back with that tutorial

Comment: thanks, but i try to make custom PageViewController. so please send that link

Comment: how many viewControllers are u trying to present in that pageViewController

Comment: 2 view in one viewControllers

Comment: thanks friend, now i make it complete view of my viewcontroller.